# intArray keeps crashing. Access violation error

Tags: c++

For some reason my `intArray` keeps crashing at multiple stages because of an access violation error, can anyone spot the problem?

```
int main()
{
   int height = 10, width = 10; //Size of the grid
   Mine mineClass;
   Grid gridClass;
   cout << "------------" << endl << "Welcome to Minesweeper." << endl << "------------" << endl << "Created by Joel Draper, 2015." << endl << "------------" << endl;
   char* grid = new char[height*width];
   gridClass.startGrid(height, width, grid); //Initialises the grid with a default value 
   mineClass.randomMine(height, width); //Initialises the grid with random mines 
   gridClass.drawGrid(height, width, grid); //Allows the user to view the grid
   while (isRunning)
   {
      mainOutput(height, width, gridClass, grid); //Prevents main function   from being filled up with output text 
      //cout << "------------" << endl;
   }
   endGame(); 
   delete[] grid;
   return 0;
}
```

Initialize the grid

```
void Grid::startGrid(int height, int width, char grid[])
{
    intArray = new int[height*width];
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            intArray[h*w] = 0;
            grid[h*w] = '*';
        }
    }
}
```

Fill Grid function (called in the set mine function, this is where the problem lies)

```
void Grid::fillGrid(int mRow, int mColumn, int width)
{
    cout << intArray;

    cout << mRow << " " << mColumn << endl;

    if (intArray[width * mRow + mColumn] == 0)
    {
        intArray[width * mRow + mColumn] = 2;
        cout << "mine placed" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your are going to have to provide an [mcve] and at least tell us what function or what part of a function is causing the issue.  If you are not sure where it is happening you can step through your code with a debugger to see where the violation occurs.

Comment: It's to do with the fill grid function, on the line     if (intArray[width * mRow + mColumn] == 0). If I comment that out, the same funciton still breaks at the line intArray[width * mRow + mColumn] = 2;

Comment: What are the values of `width`, `mRow` and `mColumn`?  What are `height` and `width` in `void Grid::startGrid(int height, int width, char grid[])`?

Comment: height and width are equal to 10, mRow and mColumn are equal to a random number between 1 and 10.

Comment: Okay.  So what happens if `mRow == 10` when you do `intArray[width * mRow + mColumn]`?

Comment: The `startGrid` initialization is wrong in `grid[h*w] = '*'` -- it should follow the same approach as in the other function.

Comment: @chi what do you mean? What other function?

Comment: @NathanOliver it proceeds as normal.

Comment: It should be something similar to `grid[width *  h + w] = ...` otherwise you are not initializing the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize `intArray` you use

```
intArray = new int[height*width];
```

With `height` and `width` being `10`.  This give you an array with the size of `100` and valid indexes of `[0, 99]`.

Then in `fillGrid()` as you said from the comments `mRow` and `mColumn` are some random number in the range of `[1, 10]`.  So when you do

```
intArray[width * mRow + mColumn]
```

you have `(10 * [1,10]) + [1,10]` as the calculation or the index.  If `mRow == 10` then we have `(100) + [1,10]` which falls outside the valid index range for `intArray`.  This is undefined behavior and should be the cause of the access violation as you are accessing memory that does not belong to the array.

If you change the range of `mRow` and `mColumn` to `[0, 9]` then the most you could have in `(10 * [0, 9]) + [0, 9]` would be `99` which falls inside the valid range of indexes for `intArray`

Comment: It throws the same issue. So you're saying do rand() % --height/rand() % --width? Also that makes no difference, even if it does or does not generate a ten, it throws the same issue.

Comment: @JoelDraper What are the values of `mRow` and `mColumn` when the access violation occurs?  Also what is the signature of `mainOutput`?

Comment: The values of mRow and mColumn when the issue occurs are 8 and 3 respectively. As for mainOutput, it's not important. Parameters are height, width, GridClass and grid, the return type is Void.

Comment: @JoelDraper The signature for `mainOutput` is important.  If it takes `gridClass` by value and you do not have a proper copy constructor then that is the cause of your problem.  This is why I said you need to have an [mcve].  There are many things that can crash a program.

Comment: Ok. The minimal example does not fill the intArray with 0's, it returns a memory address. It also only prints 'mine placed ' after some randomly generated numbers but generates all 10 randomly generated numbers.